# Why can't I connect with sftp

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, ubuntu-server, users, ubuntu-12.10

I am a newbie on ubuntu server 12.10, I was following this guide

https://gist.github.com/joshellington/2224420

I don't understand why if my */home/myuser* folder's owner is *myuser* I can't connect by sftp. So I have to do what the guide says: make *root* be the owner of */home/myuser* and then create a folder /*home/myuser/myfolder* and set *myuser* as its owner.

Then I can connect with *myuser* by sfpt and I can see *'myfolder'*. I can't upload files to */* but only to */myfolder*.

Why can't I just give the rights to write to myuser so when he connects by ftp he can upload files and create folders as he wants?

Comment: @Hennes The question is on topic here; please don't suggest asking on another site as this usually encourages cross posting (and is hurting the community here). See [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to) (same thing for Ubuntu)

Comment: This question has the answer you're looking for: [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](http://askubuntu.com/q/134425)